# issue in printing output

Tags: php, id3

i am using below code to print the id3 tags of MP2 files but the output is coming in this form

```
Array ( [FileName] => 4.mp3 [TAG] => ID3 [Version] => 3.0 [Title] => &Bahut Khubsurat Ghazal (mr-Jatt.Com) [Album] => 1Loverz Choice (A Khubsurat Ghazal) (www.mzc.in) [Author] => DJ Badboy (mr-Jatt.Com) [Track] => (www.mzc.in) )
```

but i want plain output like this

> FileName 4.mp3 Title Bahut Khubsurat Ghazal (mr-Jatt.Com) Album 1Loverz Choice (A Khubsurat Ghazal) (www.mzc.in) Author  DJ Badboy (mr-Jatt.Com) Track (www.mzc.in)

my code is

```
print_r(tagReader("4.mp3"));
// ------------------------------
function tagReader($file) {
    $id3v23 = array("TIT2","TALB","TPE1","TRCK","TDRC","TLEN","USLT");
    $id3v22 = array("TT2","TAL","TP1","TRK","TYE","TLE","ULT");
    $fsize = filesize($file);
    $fd = fopen($file, "r");
    $tag = fread($fd, $fsize);
    $tmp = "";
    fclose($fd);
    if (substr($tag, 0, 3) == "ID3") {
        $result['FileName'] = $file;
        $result['TAG'] = substr($tag, 0, 3);
        $result['Version'] = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag, 3, 1))) . "." . hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag, 4, 1)));
    }
    if ($result['Version'] == "4.0" || $result['Version'] == "3.0") {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($id3v23); $i ++) {
            if (strpos($tag, $id3v23[$i] . chr(0)) != FALSE) {
                $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v23[$i] . chr(0));
                $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag, ($pos + 5), 3)));
                $data = substr($tag, $pos, 9 + $len);
                for($a = 0; $a < strlen($data); $a ++) {
                    $char = substr($data, $a, 1);
                    if ($char >= " " && $char <= "~")
                        $tmp .= $char;
                }
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 4) == "TIT2")
                    $result['Title'] = substr($tmp, 4);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 4) == "TALB")
                    $result['Album'] = substr($tmp, 4);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 4) == "TPE1")
                    $result['Author'] = substr($tmp, 4);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 4) == "TRCK")
                    $result['Track'] = substr($tmp, 4);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 4) == "TDRC")
                    $result['Year'] = substr($tmp, 4);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 4) == "TLEN")
                    $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp, 4);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 4) == "USLT")
                    $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp, 7);
                $tmp = "";
            }
        }
    }
    if ($result['Version'] == "2.0") {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($id3v22); $i ++) {
            if (strpos($tag, $id3v22[$i] . chr(0)) != FALSE) {
                $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v22[$i] . chr(0));
                $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag, ($pos + 3), 3)));
                $data = substr($tag, $pos, 6 + $len);
                for($a = 0; $a < strlen($data); $a ++) {
                    $char = substr($data, $a, 1);
                    if ($char >= " " && $char <= "~")
                        $tmp .= $char;
                }
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 3) == "TT2")
                    $result['Title'] = substr($tmp, 3);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 3) == "TAL")
                    $result['Album'] = substr($tmp, 3);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 3) == "TP1")
                    $result['Author'] = substr($tmp, 3);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 3) == "TRK")
                    $result['Track'] = substr($tmp, 3);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 3) == "TYE")
                    $result['Year'] = substr($tmp, 3);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 3) == "TLE")
                    $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp, 3);
                if (substr($tmp, 0, 3) == "ULT")
                    $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp, 6);
                $tmp = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
foreach ( tagReader("4.mp3") as $name => $value ) {
    printf("<p>%s:%s</p>", $name, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning an array. If you want to print out the contents of the array's elements, you will have to loop through the array and print each element instead of returning the whole array.

Something like:

```
foreach ($results as $key => $value)
    echo $key . " " . $value;
```

Comment: can you please suggest how to achieve this